# Why is the notation for gain to be \$g_m\$?

Tags: amplifier, gain, terminology

I have been unable to find the origin of the notation for gain, \$g_m\$.  I'm specifically curious about transconductance.  I have a book from 1931 by [van der Bijl](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hendrik_van_der_Bijl) (who surprisingly has a wikipedia page) on the topic of vacuum tubes that uses \$g_m\$ as the notation for transconductance, which would suggest that it is very old indeed.  Assuming English origin, perhaps that the "g" is shorthand for "gain", what would the origin of the subscript "m" be?  I feel that the answer lies somewhere in German due to age of the term.  Does anyone know the origin of the term, \$g_m\$?

Comment: According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transconductance), the m is for `mutual`, since transconductance used to be (still is?) known as mutual conductance.

Comment: @helloworld922 I suspect this might be true; however, I'm trying to move beyond speculation.

Comment: It's interesting that the use of G for conductance coincides with the Dutch word "geleiding". Maybe there is link.

Comment: Why "mutual"? I think, because two "parties" are involved three nodes): (1) The differential voltage between base and emitter and (2) the current between collector and emitter. This is in contrast to the "classical" conductance where only two nodes do participate..

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Mutual conductance was named by Alan Hazeltine about 1918. Later, sometime in the 1930s, the IRE adopted transconductance as fitting better with other electrical definitions. But mutual conductance continued to be used.

Whereas gain in tube amps related plate/grid voltage gain

\$\mu = dVp / dVg~~\$ and 
\$R_p = dVp / dIp~~~~\$ for apparent plate resistance

thus gain
\$\mu =  g_mR_p\$

Comment: Great reference, I'll dig there!  I have another reference from 1919 that uses transresistance everywhere:  \$z_g=\frac{E_g}{I_G}\$

Comment: also gm is GM or Gm may refer to: Companies General Motors ,  General Mills ,  Gunn & Moore , Gaming RGM-79 GM , a mobile suit series in the video game Mobile Suit. Game Master, a person officiating in a multiplayer role-playing game Grandmaster (chess) G.M. Germany 's FIPS 10-4 country code Science and measurement Geiger–Müller tube or G-M tube,  Genetically Modified, manipulation of an organism's genome Gigametre or gigameter (Gm), one billion metres Silty gravel, in the Unified Soil Classification System Standard gravitational parameter μ = G M  , Gm (digraph) GM chassis or Guseni

Comment: so is it correct that m in gm stands for mutual conductance?

Comment: Yes but Transconductance is the more popular term for \$g_m\$ adopted by IRE in the 1930s  FYI @Unknown123

Answer (score 2):

G (or lower case italic) is the symbol/abbreviation for conductance and the m subscript stands for mutual.

[image]

Comment: The statement above the table is incorrect. G=I/V is for conductance. g=ΔIout/ΔVin is for transconductance or transfer conductance. m is for mutual.

Comment: I've moved what was posted as an answer to be a comment on this 6 year old answer. If you disagree you are welcome to say so, but please note the poster's newness here.

Comment: @user336445 sorry dude but you are way off mark.